# No targets specified and no makefile found - Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I did the following on my Raspberry Pi:

```
cd ~
wget -O opencv.zip https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/archive/3.1.0.zip
wget -O opencv_contrib.zip https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/archive/3.1.0.zip
cd ~/opencv-3.1.0/
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv/contrib-3.1.0/modules -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
make -j4
```

The `make -j4` returns `make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.`

I checked that make is installed on my device with `make --version` and found I have version 4.0. I also tried running the likes of `/usr/bin/make -j4` but continue to get the same error.

From what I've found online I think I should expect a makefile or Makefile to be in my directory but none exists.

What am I doing wrong and how do I resolve this?

**Additional Information**

I keep seeing references to a ./configuration file but I don't have this file.

Comment: Please don't use `cd ~`. Just use `cd` which is a) shorter and b) works in all shells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what went wrong when I worked through the steps outlined in my question. I didn't see any errors.

However, I deleted the build folder and ran through the following again:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv/contrib-3.1.0/modules -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
make -j4
```

This time I noticed a lot more files, including Makefile. Now when I run `make -j4` it runs without error.

Answer (score 0):

For any person who encountered this issue at any time. The problem is most usually with the options choosen.

@pac options shows minimal options that worked. Here is another example that worked most especially if you want to build the java build.

```sh
cmake \
  -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
  -D BUILD_opencv_java=ON \
  -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/path/to/opencv/contrib\
  -D BUILD_opencv_python3=ON ..
```